# Is Rigveda 6:72:1 asking to kill blashempers?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

> Rigveda 6:72:1. GREAT is this might of yours, Indra and Soma: the first high exploits were your own achievements. Ye found the Sun ye found the light of heaven: ye killed all darkness and the Gods' **blasphemers**.

Who are these blashempers and why Vedas are asking to kill them?

Comment: I think you get all these verses for your questions from some anti-Hindu website. Can you tell us which?

Comment: @Rickross I think the problem is with Translators 
See this https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06072.htm

Comment: @Rickross yes these verses are from Vedkabhed. I found the response for most of the verses but I am unable to get an explanation for some of his allegations.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan I can try help you a bit. Please refer to links of "Apologetics" in this blog - https://qr.ae/pGTbKX and also refer this https://primitivehindu.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the original verse is :

> इन्द्रासोमा महि तद्वां महित्वं युवं महानि प्रथमानि चक्रथुः। युवं
> सूर्यं विविदथुर्युवं स्व१र्विश्वा तमांस्यहतं निदश्च ॥१॥

And it means:

> हे अध्यापक और उपदेशको ! जैसे (इन्द्रासोमा) बिजुली और चन्द्रमा
> (सूर्यम्) सूर्य्य को (विविदथुः) प्राप्त होते हैं, वैसे (युवम्) तुम
> न्यायरूपी सूर्य्य को प्राप्त होओ, जैसे ये बड़े कामों को करते हैं, वैसे
> (वाम्) तुम्हारा (तत्) वह (महि) महान् (महित्वम्) बड़प्पन है और वैसे
> (युवम्) तुम (महानि) प्रशंसा योग्य (प्रथमानि) ब्रह्मचर्य्य और विद्या
> ग्रहण और दान आदि कामों को (चक्रथुः) करो (युवम्) तुम जैसे यह दोनों
> (विश्वा) समस्त (तमांसि) रात्रि के समान अविद्या आदि अन्धकारों को नष्ट
> करते हैं, वैसे अविद्या और अन्याय से उत्पन्न हुए पापों को (अहतम्) नष्ट
> करो (स्वः) सुख की प्राप्ति करो वा कराओ (निदः, च) और निन्दक तथा
> पाखण्डियों को निरन्तर नष्ट करो ॥१॥

Gist of which is:

> इस मन्त्र में वाचकलुप्तोपमालङ्कार है। हे प्रजाजनो ! जैसे सूर्य को
> प्राप्त होकर चन्द्र आदि लोक प्रकाशित होते हैं, वैसे ही अध्यापक और
> उपदेशकों का सङ्ग कर सब प्रकाशित आत्मावाले हों ॥१॥

Which when translated to english basically means:

> Just as the moon is illuminated after receiving the light from the
> sun, similarly you too become illuminated souls after receiving
> knowledge & wisdom from your teachers and preachers. Just as sun
> removes darkness everyday, similarly you too dispel darkness of
> ignorance, be happy and **continuously destroy the notions of blasphemers and
> hypocrites**

It's not asking to kill anyone physically but destroying darkness of ignorance through wisdom and knowledge!

Comment: It doesn't say that. It say  "**and**" means it a new thing.